# Flutter connectivity issue with Ganache on a real device

Tags: flutter, ethereum, blockchain, truffle, ganache

I am developing a flutter app in which I am using truffle framework and ganache. It is working perfectly on emulator. But when I connect it with my real device it gives nothing. For emulator '10.0.2.2' is working perfectly but for real android device I am using my ip '92.168.100.26' which is not working.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:web3dart/web3dart.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

class ContractLinking with ChangeNotifier {

   //my_IPv4_Address is 192.168.100.26

     final String _rpcUrl= Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://10.0.2.2:7545' :    'http://192.168.100.26:7545';
     final String _wsUrl = Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://10.0.2.2:7545' : 'ws://192.168.100.26:7545';

      final String _privateKey = '0x356943a0f6b475ee82a18103ad7f3a7d89bfe9c7e184f1ecdb87d758b13c064f';

      Web3Client? _web3client;
      bool isLoading = true;
      String? _abiCode;
      EthereumAddress? _contractAddress;
      Credentials? _credentials;
      DeployedContract? _contract;
      ContractFunction? _message;
      ContractFunction? _setMessage;

      String? deployedName;

      ContractLinking() {
         setup();
      }

      setup() async {
        _web3client = Web3Client(_rpcUrl, Client(), socketConnector: () {
        return IOWebSocketChannel.connect(_wsUrl).cast<String>();
        });

        await getAbi();
        await getCredentials();
        await getDeployedContract();
      }

      Future<void> getAbi() async {
        String abiStringFile =
        await rootBundle.loadString('build/contracts/HelloWorld.json');
        final jsonAbi = jsonDecode(abiStringFile);
        _abiCode = jsonEncode(jsonAbi['abi']);


        _contractAddress = EthereumAddress.fromHex(jsonAbi['networks']['5777']['address']);
      }

      Future<void> getCredentials() async {
        _credentials = EthPrivateKey.fromHex(_privateKey);
      }

      Future<void> getDeployedContract() async {
        _contract = DeployedContract(ContractAbi.fromJson(_abiCode!, "HelloWorld"), _contractAddress!);

        _message = _contract!.function("message");
        _setMessage = _contract!.function("setMessage");
        getMessage();
      }

      getMessage() async {
        final _mymessage = await _web3client!.call(contract: _contract!, function: _message!, params: []);

        deployedName = _mymessage[0];
        isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
      }

      setMessage(String message) async {
        isLoading = true;
        notifyListeners();
        await _web3client!.sendTransaction(_credentials!,
        Transaction.callContract(
        contract: _contract!,
        function: _setMessage!,
        parameters: [message]), chainId: 1337,
    fetchChainIdFromNetworkId: false);

        getMessage();
      }
      }
```

**This is my code for connecting with ganache. It is working fine on Emulator. Now how it will work on a real device and is the issue with ws_url or rpc_url?.**

Answer (score 0):

Changing the port in ganache settings to my ip address worked for me.